# Matlab imline and text

Tags: matlab

Thank you for your answer.  I should have been more clear.  I need a text object for every line.  Here's how far I got:

```
  function calc_slope(handle,event)

  on = get(handle,'State');

  if strcmpi(on,'on') || strcmpi(on,'off'),
      xy = imline;

      addNewPositionCallback(xy,@(pos) disp_slope(pos));     
  end


  function disp_slope(pos)

  delete(findobj(gca,'Type','text'));
  text((pos(1)+pos(2))/2,(pos(3)+pos(4))/2,['\DeltaY/\DeltaX = ',num2str((pos(4)-pos(3))/(pos(2)-pos(1))),...
       '    [\DeltaX = ',num2str(pos(2)-pos(1)),', \DeltaY = ',num2str((pos(4)-pos(3))),']']);
```

So, each toggle on the toggle button in the figure will throw in a draggable/resizable line and as I move the line the slope shows and updates, which looks pretty close to what I want.  There are, however, two issues:

1. It deletes all other text boxes except for the very last (current)
   text box of the line I'm moving around.  I want to keep the last
   value remained and shown for all existing lines.
2. If I delete a line by right-clicking on the line and choose
   "delete", it deletes the line, but not the text box and rightfully
   so.  Now I have a text box that shows the slope of the line that
   exists no longer in the figure.  I want the text box to disappear
   along with the line.

I'm having these problems and really not going anywhere because imline object behaves so much different than other typical objects and also the concept of the addNewPositionCallback is quite convoluted.

Please, somebody enlighten me on this.

Many thanks in advance,

Eric

Previous message:

I create a figure with toggle button on its toolbar by uitoggletool. The callback function for it is shown below:

```
function calc_slope(handle,event)

on = get(handle,'State');

if strcmpi(on,'on') || strcmpi(on,'off'),
   xy=imline;

   addNewPositionCallback(xy,@(xy)...
       title(['\DeltaY/\DeltaX = ',num2str((xy(4)-xy(3))/(xy(2)-xy(1))),...
             '[\DeltaX = ',num2str(xy(2)-xy(1)),...
             ',\DeltaY = ',num2str((xy(4)-xy(3))),']']));
end
```

As you can see, the example outputs the position data in the title of a figure using the 'title' command.

Is there a way to output this in a text box using the 'text' command?

I want to display the slope next to the line drawn.

Also, it will be great if the text box also gets deleted together with the associated line.

Please, help.

Thank you,

Eric

Comment: so @Eric did my answer help you?

Comment: It did, but I didn't do a good job in describing the situation.  I didn't know how to add a longer comment to your answer.  So, I just edited my original request.  Please, review and help me.  Thank you.